# How to check duplicate symbols in a large number of dynamic libraries

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries

I am working on a large C++ application which loads functionality at runtime via a plugin interface, using dynamic libraries.

Occasionally it happens that there are duplicate symbols (local classes, functions, etc forgotten to be wrapped in anonymous namespaces, other unlucky clashes with non-local namespace level symbols, etc..) loaded across libraries which leads to SEGV or other more dangerous runtime undefined behavior.

Can anyone recommend a tool/trick to catch such duplicate symbols? There is fixed list of 150-200 dlls I care to check.

Comment: Nothing you can really do. If its a public interface someone at anytime can add a function that breaks yours. A plugin interface using dll's at this scale just sounds horrible to me but that just opinion.

Comment: as I said, I only care about the clashes in a specific fixed list of dlls that I know (part of distribution). I do not care about who does what externally.

Comment: and as a side, what else other than dlls would you rather have then?

Comment: Other than DLL's I would consider an inter-process protocol (i.e. communication via networking or shared memory) approach or scripting. However, this depends on what your doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
nm -j -U <list of library names> | sort | uniq -d
```

For Windows you'll need to replace `nm` with the appropriate tool to dump the symbols from a DLL.